# I want to read all the .py files in all the folder

Tags: python

I tired this:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("D:\\Python\\Projects\\p1"):
if file.endswith(".py"):
    print(os.path.join("/Python files:", file))
```

but this only gives me the files in one folder but I want all py files of all folders
example: p1 has sub folders which have some py files and those sub folder which have some py files and so on
**"p1-->sub_folder-->sub_folder--->sub_folder"**
so, my need is to get all the **py** files in all the folders and sub folders.

Any help/suggestion will help me alot
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [rglob function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.rglob):

```
from pathlib import Path

for one_file in Path("D:\\Python\\Projects\\p1").rglob("*.py"):
    print(one_file)
```

**Edit**:
If you need to avoid a subfolder, you can do something like this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for one_file in Path("D:\\Python\\Projects\\p1").rglob("*.py"):
    if "venv" not in one_file.parts:
        print(one_file)
```

Comment: This is great! I thought of using `glob()` but then stopped. Can it be done using `glob`?

Comment: I also tired this:
'import os
root =  "D:\\Python\\Projects\\allocation"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith('.py') and not name.endswith('__init__.py'):
            print(os.path.join(name))'

Comment: What you tried? `glob` or `rglob`?

Comment: it was giving all the inbuilt files I just want the files which I created with .py

Comment: But this answer by @ndclt is working perfectly.

Comment: @Optimus this [function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html?#glob.glob)? I prefer the pathlib that gives a more usable interface for path after.

Comment: @Dinesh do you mean that in `p1` you have a virtual env you want to skip?

Comment: in p1 I just had 10-15 py files, I was getting those files along with some more files which were like 100 in built ones

Comment: You don't want to print files that are in a folder named `build`?

Comment: D:\Python\Projects\p1\checks\1.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\checks\2.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\checks\__init__.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\venv\Lib\site-packages\scandir.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\venv\Lib\site-packages\six.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\venv\Lib\site-packages\_virtualenv.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\venv\Lib\site-packages\aniso8601\compat.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\venv\Lib\site-packages\aniso8601\date.py
D:\Python\Projects\p1\venv\Lib\site-packages\aniso8601\decimalfraction.py
These are the extra files coming, which I don't want

Comment: I edit my answer with a second code avoiding to print py file which are in the `venv` folder.